# mostrar valores login google con react hooks

Tags: reactjs

estoy iniciándome en react y no se como hacer para mostrar unos valores (nombre,correo,foto) utilizando useState, tengo un botón (login google) y quiero que cuando un usuario se autentifique, mostrar unos datos en una lista.

Lo que hice fue declarar un estado con los variables que quiero mostrar, y dentro de la función de respuesta de google asignar los valores que obtengo a las variables, para después pasarlas a la lista y mostrar en pantalla, pero no hay caso, estoy un poco perdido con hooks... alguna ayuda?

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

  function Home() {

    const [datos, setDatos] = useState([          //Declaro estado
    {
     name: "",
     email: "",
     image: "",
},
 ]);

       const responseGoogle = (response) => {

        this.setState({                                 //NO FUNCIONA
       name: response.profileObj.name,
       email: response.profileObj.email,
       image: response.profileObj.imageUrl,
   });
  };

     const noResponse = (response) => {
     this.setState({
     name: " no identificado",
     email: " no identificado",
     image: null,
   });
  };

  return (
   <div>
  <h1>Autenticaciones</h1>
    <GoogleLogin
      clientId="128507741231-f29fn3id10e5erer4.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      buttonText="Iniciar Sesion"
      onSuccess={(response) => {
        this.responseGoogle(response);                //Función de donde obtengo los datos
      }}
      onFailure={(response) => {
        this.noResponse(response);
      }}
      cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
    />

   <div>
     <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li className="list-group-item">Nombre:</li>     //MOSTRAR NOMBRE
      <li className="list-group-item">Correo:</li>     //MOSTRAR CORREO
      <li className="list-group-item">                 //CARGAR IMAGEN
        Foto: <img src="" alt="" />
       </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
 export default Home;
```

Comment: ¿Haz intentado usar `setDatos` en vez de `this.setState`? Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando un componente funcional y no un componente de clase.

En componentes de clase tienes acceso a las propiedades con el `this`, en tu caso, las funciones (`noResponse`, `responseGoogle`) son variables locales de la función `Home`. Por lo tanto, no hace falta el uso del `this`.

Deberías cambiar tu código así, invocar a la funciones locales sin el `this` porque son variables locales de la función.

```html
<GoogleLogin
      clientId="128507741231-f29fn3id10e5erer4.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      buttonText="Iniciar Sesion"
      onSuccess={(response) => {
        responseGoogle(response);                //Función de donde obtengo los datos
      }}
      onFailure={(response) => {
        noResponse(response);
      }}
      cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
    />
```

[Tipos de componentes en react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)